# How to prevent v-model from being truth/false in an input checkbox (vue)

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, frontend

I currently am creating a filter popup with a list of checkboxes. On default, there should be some items selected and some not selected. I have these checkboxes connected to an object array using v-model. My problem is that when I deselect and select an item, instead of passing the object value it passes in true/false. My code is below:

```
<template>
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Filter Headers</span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
            <div class="column" v-for="(header, index) in allHeaders" :key="index">
                <input
                v-model="filteredHeaders[index]"
                type="checkbox"
                :id="index"
                >
                <label :for="index"
                >{{ header.text }}</label>
            </div>
            <p class="ml-5 mt-10"> {{ filteredHeaders }} </p>

        </v-card-text>

    </v-card>    
</template>

<script>
    export default {

        props: {
            headers: Array,
            allHeaders: Array,
        },
        computed: {
            updatedTitleOnly() {
                var titleOnly = [];
                var objectPlaceholder = {};
                console.log(this.filteredHeaders);
                    if(this.filteredHeaders.length > 0) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < this.filteredHeaders.length; i++) {
                            objectPlaceholder = this.filteredHeaders[i];
                            console.log(objectPlaceholder);

                            // titleOnly.push(objectPlaceholder.text)
                        }
                }
                    return titleOnly;
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                updateCheck: [],
                filteredHeaders: this.headers,
            }
        },

    };
</script>

<style>
    .column {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }
</style>
```

As you can see, I use a prop called allHeaders to get the list of all possible headers. Then I use a for-loop to create a checkbox for each header and assign the value of each checkbox to a value in a new array called filteredHeaders. What I want is to have these checkboxes determine what values go inside filteredHeaders. With my current code, the values get removed properly, but when I try to add them back instead of adding that object value, I get "true" or "false".

I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

When [binding to checkboxes](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#multiline-texttrue), Vue provides the `true-value` and `false-value` attributes to override the default boolean values:

```html
<input
  v-model="filteredHeaders[index]"
  type="checkbox"
  :true-value="header.text"
  :false-value="null"
>
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    const allHeaders = [{text: 'item 1'}, {text: 'item 2'}]
    const headers = []
    return {
      allHeaders,
      filteredHeaders: headers,
    }
  },

})
```

```css
.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app>
      <v-main>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">Filter Headers</span>
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <div class="column" v-for="(header, index) in allHeaders" :key="index">
              <input
                v-model="filteredHeaders[index]"
                type="checkbox"
                :true-value="header.text"
                :false-value="null"
                :id="index"
              >
              <label :for="index">{{ header.text }}</label>
            </div>
            <p class="ml-5 mt-10"> {{ filteredHeaders }} </p>

          </v-card-text>

        </v-card>
      </v-main>
    </v-app>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```